# Reconfiguring software to run on different Python version locally

Tags: command-line, python, environment-variables

I am using a shared server installed with Python 2.6.6 but this program (called RSeQC) requires Python 2.7 or higher to run; so I installed Python 2.7.13 locally. Then to enable Python 2.7.13 locally when I log in, I insert these lines into my bash_profile.

```
export PATH=/mnt/SeaGate_HDD1/ben/Python/Python-2.7.13/:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=/mnt/SeaGate_HDD1/ben/Python/Python-2.7.13
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin
```

Then after I installed RSeQC using pip, I thought it should run with no problems at all but it doesn't work. So I thought that because I am using a local Python, I should reconfigure the path for RSeQC as well. This is the instructions I got from the manual, but I am not really sure how should I reconfigure it.

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/user/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
export PATH=/home/user/bin:$PATH
```

My current configuration is as below but it doesn't work.

```
export PYTHONPATH=/mnt/SeaGate_HDD1/ben/Python/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

Can anyone advice how I should configure RSeQC properly here?

Comment: Don't touch PATH and especially PYTHONPATH: it can break other Python software. Install into a virtualenv instead e.g., `pipsi install --python python2.7 some-python-utility`